# Конверт в RealmList

Tags: java, android, kotlin, realm

Никто не подскажет как можно правильно *конвертить* в `RealmList<>`  например `Map<String, String>` ну или `List<SomeClass>`?

---

Есть некоторая модель, которую наследую от `RealmObject`
В ней есть переменная `personData`:
`var personData = RealmList<TemplatesAttribute>()` после чего я пытаюсь засунуть в конструктор данным образом:

```
 constructor(data: PersonData) : this() {
    this.personData = data.personData
}
```

И собственно здесь выдаёт ошибку, так как `personData` требует `RealmList<TemplatesAttribute>()` а он ссылается на `AttributesData` в моём dataClass'e который в свою очередь 
`var personData: AttributesData`.

Comment: а в чем проблема? Правильно это как?

Comment: @Виктор обновил вопрос, надеюсь так станет чуточку более понятно

Comment: `RealmList` - это результат выборки из БД Realm, зачем вам нужно "симулировать" выборку и помещать туда обычный List или Map?

Comment: А чем отличается, по вашему, `RealmList<SomeClass>` от `List<SomeClass>` ? Просто используйте сразу `RealmList` в полях у объектов, которые в бд будут класться, и всё. `SomeClass : RealmObject`, конечно же.